# VB6: how to add Inet control component to general toolbar?

Tags: vb6

basically I can't add Inet control in vb6 via drag and click from the general toolbar. Where is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Project (menu) --> Components --> Check "Microsoft Internet Transfer Controls 6.0" (MSINET.OCX). Now you should have the Inet icon on the toolbar.