# Upload file via ftp

Tags: file, upload, vb6, ftp

How would I upload a textfile to my ftp server using Visual Basic 6.0?

I want to upload "C:\hello.txt" to "files/hello.txt" on my server.

I've previously tried this code, without success:

```
Function UploadFile(ByVal HostName As String, _
ByVal UserName As String, _
ByVal Password As String, _
ByVal LocalFileName As String, _
ByVal RemoteFileName As String) As Boolean

Dim FTP As Inet

Set FTP = New Inet
    With FTP
        .Protocol = icFTP
        .RemoteHost = HostName
        .UserName = UserName
        .Password = Password
        .Execute .URL, "Put " + LocalFileName + " " + RemoteFileName
        Do While .StillExecuting
            DoEvents
        Loop
        UploadFile = (.ResponseCode = 0)
    End With
    Set FTP = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: And what about Ftp.url? You never assigned it in a sample you show us. And what do you mean by "without success"?

Comment: What is the result? How do you call UploadFile? (What do you set LocalFileName and RemoteFilename to? Do you incluse the path in LocalFileName What is the value of .ResponseCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop Internet Transfer Control on the form ([VB6: how to add Inet component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227462/vb6-how-to-add-inet-component)). Then use its `Execute` method. Note that there's no need to specify `Protocol` property as `Execute` figures it out from `URL` argument.

There is MSDN walkthrough on using Internet Transfer Control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733648%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" _
    (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Private Function UploadFile(ByVal sURL As String _
    , ByVal sUserName As String _
    , ByVal sPassword As String _
    , ByVal sLocalFileName As String _
    , ByVal sRemoteFileName As String) As Boolean
    'Pessimist
    UploadFile = False

    With Inet1
        .UserName = sUserName
        .Password = sPassword
        .Execute sURL, "PUT " & sLocalFileName & " " & sRemoteFileName

        'Mayhaps, a better idea would be to implement
        'StateChanged event handler
        Do While .StillExecuting
            Sleep 100
            DoEvents
        Loop

        UploadFile = (.ResponseCode = 0)
        Debug.Print .ResponseCode
    End With
End Function

Private Sub cmdUpload_Click()
    UploadFile "ftp://localhost", "", "", "C:\Test.txt", "/Level1/Uploaded.txt"
End Sub
```